# SQL server 2016 installation freeze

Tags: installation

Hope someone can help me here . 
I have no further information other than that at a later stage in setup the whole process hangs showing  install_confignonrc_cpu64
I am unable to cancel out of it even , the only way was to kill it . 
Is there any solution for that  ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My  problem was that the installer tries to download Microsoft R Open , if you have a slow connection you will see the installation freeze for a very long time without any progress bar updates or so . 
I fixed the problem by deselecting all R components since i dont need them then the installation went smooth .

Comment: Both my installer and the Windows Task Manager locked up; after a reboot I followed the above steps successfully.

Comment: I didn't want to restart the installation so what I did is I disabled the LAN port. An error saying that Python installation failed, but all other stuff installed correctly!

Comment: Just faced the same issue, and here is the prove that this statement seems to be correct - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLJvd.png - Image is from resmon (Resource Monitor) and you can clearly see a process "RSetup" downloading stuff

Comment: Ending the task RSetup.exe via Windows Task Manager appears to have resolved the problem for me. The installer reports Microsoft R was successfully installed, but I have not confirmed that's the case yet.

Comment: I didn't have any R components and still experienced the same issue. Cuong Nguyen's blurb below solved my issue by turning the firewall on for a minute or two.

Comment: Thanks @MarlonAllanSupetran temporarily disabled all my network adapters, that solved it.

Comment: internet issue confirmed, used a faster connection and it worked quickly.

Answer (score 9):

just had the same problem which is why I found this question.
Fixed the problem by closing the original media install menu window (where I'd selected "New SQL Server standalone" which is the first option).
The install window then carried on.

Comment: It eventually worked. i just had to be patient and wait another two minutes.

Answer (score 9):

Just leave it "Stuck" - it is doing a Download in the background, I left the PC for a couple hours while doing some errands, and then..boom- All set.

Comment: and probably collapse all windows

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same problem with you, the simple way that i have find is turn on Windows firewall then wait a minute after that it will auto complete setup success. Hope this work in your case .

Thanks,
Cuong.

Answer (score 1):

Disable and stop the windows update service and then start the installation. After the installation is complete put the service back on.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Install gets stuck on sqlrsconfigaction_install_confignonrc_cpu64 (SQL Server 2016 using standalone installer, also when installing on Azure VMs)

Resolution:

1. Stop the install (Taskman -> Kill Process)
2. Open regedit
3. Navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\
   ```
4. Add New Key Called: AppCompat

   You should have this once added:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AppCompat
   ```
5. Add New DWORD entries as stated below to the AppCompat key:

   ```
   DWORD: DisableEngine Value = 1
   DWORD: DisablePCA Value = 1
   DWORD: SbEnable Value = 0
   ```
6. Check the following location as the above key you added should also be here:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\
   ```
7. Restart the installation.

Comment: Use this solution with caution...disabling the application compatibility engine may have unintended consequences for other programs. https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_7_2008R2&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.ApplicationCompatibility::AppCompatTurnOffEngine

Answer (score 0):

I closed everything and rebooted.  Not sure if maybe having Visual Studio open or something else prevented it from installing, but it got stuck.