# SQL Server 2016 install freezing at install_vc10redist_cpu64_action

Tags: sql-server

Steps to install:

1. Right click and mount.
2. Double click setup.exe.
3. Ran system config checker and it passed.
4. Selected new sql server stand alone install...

Troubleshooting attempted:

1. Installed C++ 2010 Redist.
2. Closed sql server installation center window.
3. Let install run for 3 hours to see if it would finish.

[image: Freeze Status Screen]

[image: Installed Programs]

[image: Features to Install]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL server 2016 installation freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017915/sql-server-2016-installation-freeze)

Comment: Taking a look now.

Comment: @Igor Unfortunately not. I saw that first and tried every troubleshooting step I saw there.